# How to check failed module during deployment - Maven multi module

Tags: maven, maven-2, jboss7.x, multi-module

I am deploying application to Jboss AS 7.1.1.Final using Maven multi module configuration. The 'jboss-as-maven-plugin' plugin with version 7.4.Final is used to deploy to AS using remote deployment. I have a parent POM with multiple modules as shown below.

```
<modules>
    <module>ProjectA</module>
    <module>ProjectB</module>
    <module>ProjectC</module>
    <module>ProjectD</module>
</modules>
```

Configuration in master POM

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.Final</version>
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
            <filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename>
            <username>${userName}</username>
            <password>${password}</password>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Configuration in each module's POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <filename>${project.build.finalName}.jar</filename>
        <username>${userName}</username>
        <password>${password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There has been deployment errors related to connection timeout to Jboss server that can occure while deploying any of the module configured. I am planning on writting script to check when a specific module failed from multi module configuration, will try to redeploy failed module. For this to happen I would need to know which of these module failed during deployment. Is it possible to know while running maven as following command?

> mvn clean package install jboss-as:deploy -DskipTests
>   -DuserName=username -Dpassword=password -Ddeploy.host=10.10.10.10 -Ddeploy.port=9999

Comment: Out of curiosity what kinds of errors are you seeing? Is it just the occasional module or if one fails do they all fail?

Comment: I am having another thread going on issues I am encountering at [Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757757/could-not-connect-to-remote-localhost9999-the-connection-timed-out-jboss-7-1). Also error might occur on any of the modules causing the entire build failures as the modules are dependant on each other.